# how to solve system of quadratic equations (mod N)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Given a two equations:
$${(ax_1 + b)}^2 = c_1 \pmod N$$
$${(ax_2 + b)}^2 = c_2 \pmod N$$

- $N=p.q$
- $p$ and $q$ are large primes
- $x_1, x_2$ and $c_1, c_2$ are known

Is it computationally feasible to solve this system for $a$ and $b$? If not prove that the problem is intractable. Could it help if we have more than two equations?

Comment: PS: Use `/pmod`

Answer (score 0):

First we have to make sure that the c_i are quadratic residues mod N, usind Legendre symbols. After that we solve each equation in turn and take the intersection of the solution sets.

Comment: how can I use Legendre symbols if p and q are unknowns?